# C Reading binary file with fread()

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, fread

im trying to read file from stdin with hex values:

0x0a

0x00 0x0a

0x61 0x00 0x61 0x00 0x0a

0x00 0x00 0x00

```
int i = 0;
unsigned char x = 0;        
            while(x != 0x0a && x != EOF){
                fread(&x, 1 , 1, stdin);
                tab[i] = x;
                i++;
            }
```

With this loop i'm getting segmentation fault with last line.

Comment: It sure would help to know what `tab` is and how it is declared.  I assume that's where the crash is and not `i++` which is the last line.

Comment: Is this all code? Look at 'tab' definition.

Comment: Do you have enough size `tab`?

Comment: Check return value of `fread(&x, 1 , 1, stdin)` and stop when it does not return 1.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the declaration of `tab` we can't really be certain what is triggering the segfault (most likely out of bounds access to `tab`).

However, you shouldn't use `fread` with `stdin` - `fread` is for reading binary files, it will read the binary representation of every character on the screen.
You are actually reading a byte representation of a character, pretty much the same as if you were doing `x = getchar()` or `scanf("%c", &x)`

So you will read "0x0a\n0x00 0x0a\n" etc.

Now, you are testing it against the value of `0x0a`, which is actually a `'\n'`, so you likely aren't reading past the first line.

What you want to be doing is:

```
scanf("0x%x", &x);
```

Which will read a single hex value, such as "0x0a", which you can then check against that constant above.

Another thing - You have declared x as an `unsigned char`, but are testing it against `EOF`, which is an int, `-1`. I'm surprised the compiler didn't give you a warning there. You should pretty much always read the value into an int, so I'd redeclare it as `int`.

Also, when reading binary files (i.e. using `fread`), you will never read the EOF value, since that is a valid value to be found in the file. Instead, if end of file has been reached, `fread` will return 0. And you can check whether it has been reached using `feof(file)`.